# MaxReceivedMessageSize (6553 6) foi excedida. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, json, web-service, rest, soap

Estou consumindo um web Service por SOAP, porém a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

> A cota máxima de tamanho de mensagens de entrada (6553 6)foi excedida.
>   Para aumentar a cota, use a propriedade MaxReceivedMessageSize  no
>   elemento de associação apropriado.

Procurei em vários artigos e fóruns sobre como resolver este problema. Realizei o ajuste no Binding - aumentado a cota máxima -, porém a mensagem persiste.

Alguém teria alguma outra alternativa para solucionar este tipo de problema? Deixo abaixo o SOAP para verificarem as propriedades que utilizei.

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging maxSizeOfMessageToLog="1000000" />
        </diagnostics>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WorkflowWebServiceSoap" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000"
                    maxBufferSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="WorkflowWebServiceSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"
                        maxBufferSize="1000000" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="MINHA URL DE WEBSERVICE"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WorkflowWebServiceSoap12"
                contract="ServiceReference1.WorkflowWebServiceSoap" name="WorkflowWebServiceSoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: O Serviço é seu ou de terceiros? Se for seu, você ja configurou o maxReceivedMessageSize no lado do serviço também ?

Comment: @JulioSoares, estou utilizando o serviço de terceiros... Seria uma pendencia deles ? Obrigado =)

Comment: Não deve ser não. Já tentou colocar o valor máximo permitido para maxReceivedMessageSize ? Tente colocar maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" no seu web.config.

Comment: @JulioSoares Obrigado. Infelizmente já tentei colocar  este valor, porem a mesma mensagem é exibida. Teria alguma outra possibilidade ? Obrigado novamente.